# How to view PDFs in Android webview through Google Docs in an Appgyver Steroids App?

Tags: javascript, android, pdf, steroids

I am developing an app with *"Appgyver Steroids"* and part of the app involves looking at a website which has a number of PDFs available to view.

I would like to enable viewing of the PDFs with the Google Docs viewer but don't know how to code this. There are plenty of java solutions for this (which makes sense as it is Android), but I'm looking for a javascript technique that I can use in Steroids.

Answer (score 1):

Android native web browser doesn't support PDF, which sucks.

Maybe this could be a workaround?
https://docs.google.com/viewer